# How to use nls with caret to do cross-validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret, nls

I have fit several models using `nls` to the same data and am trying to figure out how to use `caret` to do K-fold cross-validation (eg., [here](https://www.statology.org/how-to-perform-cross-validation-for-model-performance-in-r/)). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566335/how-to-use-statsnls-non-linear-least-squares-regression-in-caret) asked a general question about using `nls` in `caret` for a single model. However, the answer referred them to [this resource](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html), which is beyond my understanding (ie, how to adapt for `nls`), especially for fitting several different `nls` functions.

Here is example data and examples of the model objects fit with `nls`:

```
library("caret")

df <-
  structure(list(c = c(123.86, 208.75, 141.5, 230.73, 143.4, 209.31, 
  161.15, 130.87, 232.05, 121.61, 176.31, 139.01, 131.92, 156.61, 
  150.05, 121, 134.12, 146.83, 181.39, 115, 147.87, 161.49, 107.65, 
  115.51, 144.11), q = c(0.028, 0.004, 0.049, 0.001, 0.049, 0.004, 
  0.016, 0.015, 0.003, 0.026, 0.002, 0.009, 0.148, 0.012, 0.017, 
  0.086, 0.02, 0.038, 0.003, 0.031, 0.011, 0.032, 0.132, 0.093, 
  0.026)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame"))

# Model 1
eq1 <- function(q,a,n) (a*q**(-1/n))
eq1_fit <- nls(c ~ eq1(q,a,n), data=df,start=list(a=380, n=5))

# Model 2
eq2 <- function(q,h,g,n,c0) (h*exp(-g*q**(1/n))+c0)
eq2_fit <- nls(c ~ eq2(q,h,g,n=5,c0=6), data=df,start=list(h=100,g=1))
```

There are several additional models all fit using `nls` on the same data that I would like to do 5-fold or 10-fold CV on following the example or something similar to [shown here](https://www.statology.org/how-to-perform-cross-validation-for-model-performance-in-r/). A solution using `tidymodels` and `workflowsets` would also work too. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with the `vfold_cv()` function in the `rsample` package, which is in the `tidymodels` ecosystem.

```r
df <-
  structure(list(c = c(123.86, 208.75, 141.5, 230.73, 143.4, 209.31, 
                       161.15, 130.87, 232.05, 121.61, 176.31, 139.01, 131.92, 156.61, 
                       150.05, 121, 134.12, 146.83, 181.39, 115, 147.87, 161.49, 107.65, 
                       115.51, 144.11), q = c(0.028, 0.004, 0.049, 0.001, 0.049, 0.004, 
                                              0.016, 0.015, 0.003, 0.026, 0.002, 0.009, 0.148, 0.012, 0.017, 
                                              0.086, 0.02, 0.038, 0.003, 0.031, 0.011, 0.032, 0.132, 0.093, 
                                              0.026)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                          "data.frame"))


library(rsample)
library(tidyverse)
## define equations 
eq1 <- function(q,a,n) (a*q**(-1/n))
eq2 <- function(q,h,g,n,c0) (h*exp(-g*q**(1/n))+c0)


eq1_fit <- nls(c ~ eq1(q,a,n), data=df,start=list(a=380, n=5))
eq2_fit <- nls(c ~ eq2(q,h,g,n=5,c0=6), data=df,start=list(h=100,g=1))

y <- df$c
## create the squared errors getting model predictions
## from the assessment partition
r1 <- (y - predict(eq1_fit, newdata=df))
r2 <- (y - predict(eq2_fit, newdata=df))


e1 <- (y - predict(eq1_fit, newdata=df))^2
e2 <- (y - predict(eq2_fit, newdata=df))^2





## define function that will do the model fitting and assessment
cv_mods <- function(split, ...){
  ## fit models with the analysis partition
  eq1_fit <- nls(c ~ eq1(q,a,n), data=analysis(split),start=list(a=380, n=5))
  eq2_fit <- nls(c ~ eq2(q,h,g,n=5,c0=6), data=analysis(split),start=list(h=100,g=1))
  ## take the dependent variable from the assessment partition
  y <- assessment(split)$c
  ## create the residuals  getting model predictions
  ## from the assessment partition
  e1 <- (y - predict(eq1_fit, newdata=assessment(split)))
  e2 <- (y - predict(eq2_fit, newdata=assessment(split)))
  ## return the cross-validated residuals from both models as 
  ## a data frame. 
  data.frame(e1 = e1, e2 = e2)
}

## estimate the cross-validation 
## the vfold_cv function sets up the cross-validation partitions
## I used 10 repeats here for speed, but in the "real world" you 
## would probably want lots more 
out <- vfold_cv(df,
                v=10,
                repeats = 10) %>%
  ## estimate the cv on all of the partitions
  mutate(err = map(splits,
                   cv_mods)) %>% 
  ## unnest the error column to turn it into two 
  ## columns in your data frame
  unnest(err)  

## First analysis: Pr(mod1 better than mod2)
out1 <- out %>% 
  ## group by repeat 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  ## calculate the standard deviation of the errors for each level of id
  summarise(across(e1:e2, ~sd(.x))) %>% 
  ## calculate the probability across repeats that model 1 is better
  ## than model 2
  summarise(p_eq1_better = mean(e1<e2))

out1
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   p_eq1_better
#>          <dbl>
#> 1            1


## alternatively, follow similar steps to above, 
## but get the average cross-validation error 
## for each model: 
out2 <- out %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  ## sum up the sums of squared errors across partitions
  summarise(across(e1:e2, ~sd(.x))) %>% 
  ## calculate average CV error:
  summarise(across(e1:e2, ~mean(.x)))

out2
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      e1    e2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  19.7  21.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The code works, but the errors seem overly high. Are you sure they are calculated correctly? For example, if I calculate the RMSE (which is ultimately what I need) for eq1 without doing the cross-validation it's ~18. Assuming I am calculating RMSE correctly by taking the `sqrt` of the calculated avg CV error at the end of `out2`, I get an RMSE of ~99. Is this to be expected? Or are we duplicating error somewhere?

Comment: Is this line of code from `out2` duplicating error? `summarise(across(sse1:sse2, ~sum(.x)))`. If I skip this chunk of code, run the rest, and then take the `sqrt` SSEs for each partition and then take the mean of those values to get the mean RMSE, the mean RMSE for eq1 is ~31. Is this more correct?

Comment: I just updated the code.  I was taking the sum of squared errors rather than the RMSE.  The updated code gives the RMSE (sd of residuals) for each repeated CV run and then either averages them or generates a probability as in the original example.  These numbers (19.7 for mod 1 and 21.2 for mod 2) are more in line with your expectations.